# String does not have a member named setValue for Core Data in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have done NSFetchRequest on an entity in coreData like so

```
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Users")
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error)
```

I have the iterated through so I can get to the valueForKey object like so:

```
if results!.count > 0 {

            for result: AnyObject in results! {
                if let rStatus = result.valueForKey("relationshipStatus") as? String{
                    rStatus.setValue(self.RelationshipStatus.text, forKey: "relationshipStatus") //GETTING AN ERROR HERE SAYING STRING DOES NOT HAVE A MEMBER NAMED 'SET VALUE'
                    println("Current User updated status to core data")
                    context.save(&self.error)
                }
            }
        }
```

Although I am getting an error saying 'String does not have a member named setValue'. Is there anyway of getting around this as I want to set the particular key only?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because you're trying to call a method on `String` and that method doesn't exist. Instead you should be calling it on `result`:

```
result.setValue(self.RelationshipStatus.text, forKey: "relationshipStatus")
```

Comment: But then I won't be setting the value on the correct object. I want to specifically setValue on the key "relationshipStatus"??

Comment: That is a property on the result (the User object), not the string